# Pickle Error in Pyspark While Airflow Migration

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I'm migrating from old Airflow to New Airflow Environment.
While migrating to new airflow env, I encountered [pickle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q53AW.png).
I understood the object need to be pickled because of RDD operation closure.
And I also understood that the object that i declared is cannot be pickled because of [some issues](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/1029) in redis cluster library.

```
rc = RedisCluster(
    startup_nodes=config["redis"]["mydashboard"]["nodes"],
    password=redis_pwd,
    decode_responses=True,
)


def write_to_redis(row) -> None:
    rc.set(
        name=row.mid, value=row.messages, ex=config["redis"]["ttl"]
    )

result_df.rdd.foreach(write_to_redis)
```

But I can't understand why this code is executed well in old airflow environment.
**The difference between two environment** was

1. When executing python code, old environment use python command instead of pyspark or spark-submit. While new environment use pyspark command
2. Old Airflow environment use celeray executor while new env use k8s executor

Both environment use master option as yarn.
If you need more information, ask to me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brief explanation why I believe the picking error happens:

When you perform a `foreach` method, the callable function (in your case `write_to_redis`) gets executed on an executor node in Spark. What this means, is that your class (`rc`) gets initialised on the driver node and it gets used on the executor nodes (which usually is entirely other servers / instances etc).

What Spark attempts to do, is to pickle the initialised class and then "copy" it into all the executor nodes to be used by your function. Some
initialised classes cannot be pickled unfortunately (example boto3 connections).

To solve this, you could try initialising the class inside the method you call in the function like below:

```
def write_to_redis(row) -> None:
    rc = RedisCluster(
        startup_nodes=config["redis"]["mydashboard"]["nodes"],
        password=redis_pwd,
        decode_responses=True,
    )
    rc.set(
        name=row.mid, value=row.messages, ex=config["redis"]["ttl"]
    )

result_df.rdd.foreach(write_to_redis)
```

If you will be using this be mindful of the number of connections you will be opening up to your Redis cluster since each executor node where this function is called will open up one connection.